# Memory Stream Errors Out on Second Try on Mobile Device Chrome

Tags: c#, mobile, asp.net-core-2.0, memorystream

I have a Core 2 application that allow the user to upload a photo. It works perfectly on my PC browser but when I use it on my mobile device it doesn't work after the first use.

I've tried restarting everything. Publishing the site again. No luck.

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
model.ChangeOfBrokerModel.Image.CopyToAsync(memoryStream); <--Errors out here
System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
image.Save(_env.WebRootPath + "\\CertIMG\\" + certPhotoPath);
}
```

Comment: Whats the error?

Answer (score 1):

You call async-method without awaiting result - need to add [await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/await)-operator:

```
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    await model.ChangeOfBrokerModel.Image.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
    // ..
}
```